# Is there any way to see order source in Orders table in magento admin?

Tags: admin, order-grid

I've google it, but I found only one thread in Magento Forum http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40399/ but their forum engine always returns "Your message field is empty" error.

That's why I'll ask here.

We've used Bigcommerce, and they have nice feature in admin backend. In order table you can see the order sourse. It displays like icons (Frontend, backend, frontend tablet, frontend smartphone etc)

I need to implement it in our Magento instance. We have multistore running that shares same catalog (http://doorsandbeyond.com). I need to display the order source in admin backend.

I need to see which orders were submitted via backend, and which were placed from frontend.

I have some idea like to check website's code and display some string, but I don't know how to implement it. Then I think I can develop it to show the device type for the frontend orders, and admin's (Sales person's) name for backend orders, etc.

Any push in the direction will be appreciated

Thanks
Sharif

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can create extension which will save order_id and source_type in separate table. For example yourextension_order_source_type.
After you will create observer to listen to `sales_order_place_after` event.
Now every time when order is creating you can get somehow source type and save it with order_id.

To display it you can just create your own block and add it to order edit page.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Oleksii for your input. I'll digg there. As I'll get some results, I'll post them here.